# How to Send Array String in Zeep

Tags: python-3.x, zeep

I have this below soap envelope where I have send string array.

```
  <apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">Ab12-Ab12-Ab12-Ab12</apiKey>§
     <baseScheduleRollout xsi:type="flex:baseScheduleRollout" xmlns:flex="http://app.quinyx.com/soap/FlexForce">
        <badgeNos xsi:type="flex:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
            <item1>1022</item1>
            <item2>1030</item2>
            <item2>10112330</item2>
        </badgeNos>
        <fromDateTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2020-11-05T00:00:00</fromDateTime>
        <toDateTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2020-11-24T00:00:00</toDateTime>
```

I know how to send a soap request and my complextype is okay. But I think my string array passing system is wrong. Though I tried to use anyObject but still not working

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd
import datetime
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zeep.transports import Transport

wsdl = "https://api.quinyx.com/FlexForceWebServices.php?wsdl"

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password')
client = Client(wsdl, transport=Transport(session=session))

ArrayOfString = client.get_element('ns0:ArrayOfObject')
badgeNo = ArrayOfString(['146223'])


data = { "apiKey" : "apikey" , 
         "baseScheduleRollout" :{
                                "badgeNos":badgeNo,
                                "fromDateTime":xsd.SkipValue,
                                "toDateTime":xsd.SkipValue
                               }
       }
result = client.service.wsdlGetBaseScheduleRolledoutHours(**data)
result
```

Error

> LookupError: No element 'ArrayOfObject' in namespace https://api.quinyx.com/soap/FlexForce. Available elements are:  -